# How to get plugin from component using component query on Extjs 4.1?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I want to add event listener to plugin on Controller.like http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller  It seems different to get plugin using component query than normal component.
Is it possible to get plugin from component using component query?

Here is my component

```
Ext.define('App.view.file.List',{
     rootVisible: false, 
     extend:'Ext.tree.Panel',
     alias:'widget.filelist',
     viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop', 
            allowParentInsert:true 
        }
    },
    //etc ...
```

Can i get **treeviewdragdrop** plugin using component query like

```
Ext.define('App.controller.FileManagement', {
    extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores:['Folder'],
    views:['file.List','file.FileManagement'],
    refs:[
        { ref:'fileList', selector:'filelist' }
    ],
    init:function () {
        this.control({  
            'filelist > treeviewdragdrop':{drop:this.drop}  // <-- here is selector
        });
    },
    // etc ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't because a plugin is not a component, thus no selector will find it.

Also, the drop event is fired by the treeview, so the treeview is really what you want to hook to.

This will work:

```
init:function () {
    this.control({  
        'filelist > treeview': {drop:this.drop}
    });
},
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no straightforward approach to do that. If I were in your shoes I would, probably, made tree to fire needed event when the plugin fires its event:

```
// view
Ext.define('App.view.file.List',{
     // ...
     viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
            pluginId: 'treeviewdragdrop', // <-- id is needed for plugin retrieval
            allowParentInsert:true 
        }
    },
    initComponent: funcion() {
      var me = this;
      me.addEvents('viewdrop');
      me.callParent(arguments);
      me.getPlugin('treeviewdragdrop').on('drop', function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition, eOpts) {
        // when plugin fires "drop" event the tree fires its own "viewdrop" event
        // which may be handled via ComponentQuery
        me.fireEvent('viewdrop', node, data, overModel, dropPosition, eOpts);
      });
    },
    // ...
```

Controller:

```
// controller
Ext.define('App.controller.FileManagement', {
    // ...
    init:function () {
        this.control({  
            'filelist':{viewdrop:this.drop}  // <-- here is selector
        });
    },
    // etc ....
```

Comment: I don't think you need the whole InitComponent bit. The drop of the plugin is mirrored in the view. So the controller init just select the component, then getView(), then .on('drop'... ).

Comment: `addEvents` is deprecated. Just use `me.fireEvent('viewdrop', node, data, overModel, dropPosition, eOpts);`